# What does tf.no_op() do?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

```
with tf.dependencies([train_step,variable_average_op]):
    train_op = tf.no_op('train')
.....
_, loss, steps = sess.run([train_op, loss, global_step],feed_dict...)
```

I'm confused what is the function of tf,no_op() here

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: yup, it says do nothing...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the documentation says, [`tf.no_op()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/no_op) does nothing. However, when you create a `tf.no_op()` inside a [`with tf.control_dependencies([x, y, z]):`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) block, the op will gain control dependencies on ops `x`, `y`, and `z`. Therefore it can be used to group together a set of side effecting ops, and give you a single op to pass to `sess.run()` in order to run all of them in a single step.

Comment: so the reason that we write no_op within the block is to activate the control_dependencies block to run ops x,y,z in the specified order?

Comment: That's almost right: we need to create an op in the `control_dependencies` block to cause those dependencies to be added. However the order is slightly more subtle: (assuming there are no other edges between them) `x`, `y`, and `z` can run in *any* order with respect to each other; and the `control_dependencies` just ensure that they all happen *before* the `no_op`.